# Can't GET draft posts via REST API from headless frontend

Tags: rest-api, json, cookies, authentication, nonce

I have a headless install of Wordpress on `v5.4.0`. The frontend can't GET any post that is in `draft` status, though when accessing the API url directly the data is returned without an issue. I'm assuming this is cookie/auth related. Note, I'm dynamically grabbing the `nonce` values from the backend, showing full strings here for the sake of argument. Here's my setup and screenshots of the responses:

Request URL: `http://wordpress.test/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/19060?wpnonce=23c01b3b12&_embed=true`

Called on the frontend using `isomorphic-unfetch` (also tried with `axios`) like so:

```
fetch("http://wordpress.test/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/19060?wpnonce=23c01b3b12&_embed=true", {
  credentials: "include"
})
```

Here's the request/response from the frontend, which is not working (this *does* work for all `published` content):

[image]

With this body:

```
{
  "code":"rest_forbidden",
  "message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.",
  "data":{
  "status":401
  }
}
```

When trying to access the data directly, I see two different responses depending on the `wpnonce` query parameter underscore:

This works (using `_wpnonce`) returning the proper JSON data:

`http://wordpress.test/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/19060?_wpnonce=23c01b3b12&_embed=true`

Details:

[image]

This does not (using `wpnonce`):

`http://wordpress.test/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/19060?wpnonce=23c01b3b12&_embed=true`

Details:

[image]

Returns the same response error that the frontend does:

```
{
  "code":"rest_forbidden",
  "message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.",
  "data":{
  "status":401
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've also tried the `X-WP-Nonce` header mentioned here (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) and it doesn't seem to be recognized:

```
fetch(postUrl, {
  credentials: "include",
  headers: {
    "X-WP-Nonce": wpnonce
  }
})
```

[image]

```
{"code":"rest_cookie_invalid_nonce","message":"Cookie nonce is invalid","data":{"status":403}}
```

**EDIT 2:**

On a clean install of WP and a new barebones frontend (html + jquery) I'm seeing the same issue. However, I find that the nonce is valid when generating the preview link, but invalid when WP tries to verify using `rest_cookie_check_errors`. How can the same nonce with the same action (`wp_rest`) fail verification?:

[image]

I'm seeing that `wp_get_session_token()` is failing because there's no cookie found on REST requests. (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L2140) Isn't the point of the `nonce` to not require cookies? Could it be an issue with cross-domain cookie paths?

I am sending credentials in the XHR. Here's my frontend test code:

```
// GET page with Nonce header
$.ajax({
  url: postUrl,
  method: "GET",
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", wpnonce);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  }
})
```

Two questions:

1. Mainly, how can I get draft post data using nonce values from the frontend?
2. Why in the world would the `_wpnonce` / `wpnonce` query vars show different results on the frontend and backend?

Comment: Please review the documentation for authentication with the REST API: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/ Both your questions are answered.

Comment: Edited to note the X-WP-Nonce header in the get request. Am I missing something else?

Comment: It sounds like your nonce is recognised, but is invalid, are you sure it's generated correctly?

Comment: It is generated using this line, which is sent to the frontend: wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' );

Comment: Also, regarding the validity of the nonce value, when vieewing the JSON URL directly: 

This works: 
`http://wordpress.test/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/19060?_wpnonce=df05ad04e1&_embed=true`

But this does not, showing an `invalid nonce` 401 response error: 
`http://wordpress.test/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/19060?_embed=true`

Indicating that the nonce is working as expected.

Comment: Ah, sorry again, I didn't really notice you already confirmed the validity of the nonce. :p But you can try once again and make sure to send just the nonce header and no query strings in the URL, just to see if it works that way. If it doesn't, you can try deactivating plugins.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding what the problem is. Your question says that it works if you use `_wpnonce`. The documentation explains that you need to use `_wpnonce`, not `wpnonce`, so why can't you just do that?

Comment: @SallyCJ I tried only sending the `X-WP-Nonce` header, and now published and draft pages are forbidden on frontend requests. I'm setting the `nonce` with `wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' );` and seeing it up date over time. It appears to be valid using `wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'wp_rest')` Also, I've just spun up a fresh WP install, wired to the same frontend and seeing the same issues :/


@JacobPeattie Directly viewing the REST URL works with, but viewing draft posts/pages on the frontend does not. That is the issue. I need to be able to view unpublished page data on the frontend.

Comment: Edited question to show results of a clean install of WP and a barebones frontend (html + jquery) where nonce verification fails during the REST request, even though the values are the same.

Comment: @theLucre, if you originally mentioned 'from external domain' in the question, I would've just suggested you to use an authentication plugin (just like JWT) because from remote apps, that's what the WordPress core suggests. After all, I don't think it's a good idea to include the cookies in the request (the `credentials: 'include'` in `fetch()`).

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ. I assumed headless WP meant two domains. Apologize for any confusion and I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so technically I didn't solve the issue that prevented me from accessing posts in `draft` status from an external domain where the frontend is hosted using only `nonce` values. My guess is that the `logged_in` cookie was not set/could not be read on the frontend side to verify the `nonce` value during an external AJAX request.

That being said, I installed the JWT Authentication for the WP REST API plugin (https://github.com/Tmeister/wp-api-jwt-auth) and now require admins to login once on the frontend preview page to set the token in local storage.

Comment: You did solve it. That's the only solution. You cannot access cookies across domains, and as noted in the documentation that I linked you in the very first comment: "It is important to keep in mind that this authentication method relies on WordPress cookies. As a result this method is only applicable when the REST API is used inside of WordPress and the current user is logged in. In addition, the current user must have the appropriate capability to perform the action being performed."